# Loop through multiple columns and make a plot for each in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where the first column is "Year" and the next fifty are data for each US state. I want to generate multiple plots in one pdf matching each "state" column with the "year" column (ie [,1] and [,2], [,1] and [,3], ... [,1] and [,50].

I thought looping through columns 2-50 would be a good solution but I cannot get it to work within the plot function. I am new to loops so I'm not really sure how to proceed. Below is a sample from my dataset and the part of the code I am having trouble with

```
testUS:
Year    ME   NH    VT   MA   RI   CT    NY
1953    4017 1579 5057 12215 1582 9252  23507
1954    5265 1351 1733 18561 633  8402  21002
1955    740  788  2214 9719  787  3958  22317
1956    985  184  1537 6458  957  5575  26639

pdf("testUSgraph.pdf")
for (i in 2:50) {
  plot(testUS[,1], testUS[,i])
}
dev.off
```

The error message I am getting:

```
function (which = dev.cur()) 
{
    if (which == 1) 
        stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)")
    .External(C_devoff, as.integer(which))
    dev.cur()
}
<bytecode: 0x1075edc30>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

In addition, any time I assign testUS[,i] to a variable, the variable only calls up the data for one state (ie only shows column 50's data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`,

```
library(ggplot2)

col_names <- colnames(df)
col_names <- col_names[-1]

for (i in col_names){
    plot <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=df$Year, y=i)) +
    geom_point()
    print(plot)
}
```

This should return them as individual plots.

**edit:** to return plots in the same view, and save as pdf,

```
col_names <- colnames(df)
col_names <- col_names[-1]

plot_list <- list()

for (i in col_names){
    plot <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=df$Year, y=i)) +
    geom_point()
    plot_list[[i]] <- plot
}
plot_grob <- arrangeGrob(grobs=plot_list)
pdf("testUSgraph.pdf")
grid.arrange(plot_grob)
dev.off()
```

(The problem with saving pdf in your initial code might be because you forgot the parentheses, `dev.off` should be `dev.off()`)

Comment: Same problem, keeps plotting the 50th column only.  When I try to pdf/dev.off, I receive the same error message as above.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't press the left arrow on the plot section to cycle to previous plots? It's definitely only returning one plot?

Comment: ope, yes sorry that is correct. Thanks...  Is it possible to then take that and make a combined pdf with each graph? The error message is still given when I try to do that.

Comment: No worries. Check my edit for making a combined plot. If the pdf code doesn't work you should be able to click Export --> save as PDF.

Comment: Hello! I could use your code in my script, however, I need to plot pie charts instead of points looping through the col_names. I've tried to create the percentages. Do you help me to fix this code `plot_list <- list()
for (i in col){
    plot <- ggplot(ds_original_t1, aes_string(x=1, y=i)) +
     geom_bar( stat = "identity",
                 fill = "lightblue", colour = "black")
     plot_list[[i]] <- plot
}`

Comment: Hi Luis, ask a new question with a reproducible example.